# Matlab - Splitting a column into two (efficiently)

Tags: matlab, matrix

I had previously wrote some code to split 3 columns into 4, however the code was very inefficient and time consuming. As I am working with millions of rows it wasn't suitable. (Below is my previous code)

```
tline = fgetl(fid);

ID=tline(1:4);
IDN = str2double(ID);

Day=tline(6:8);
DayN = str2double(Day);

HalfHour=tline(9:10);
HalfHourN = str2double(HalfHour);

Usage=tline(12:end);
UsageN = str2double(Usage);
```

There must be a more efficient and quicker way of doing this?

Going back to basics, I have produced a x by 3 matrix. but require an x by 4 matrix

To show what I am trying to do, examining one row -
I am trying to change

```
1001 36501 1005
```

to

```
1001 365 01 1005
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Edit:

The second column I am trying to divide into two, is always composed of 5 characters. I am trying to get the first 3 characters into their own column, likewise for the remaining characters.

Comment: Are you editing a csv/txt file? If so, use [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/). Place your cursor in the first line after the "1001 365" and choose Edit->Column Editor->Text Insert to insert a whitespace column.

Comment: In general changing numbers to strings is going to slow things down a lot.

Comment: Thomas good suggestion, but for some reason the columns stop being sperated around the millionth row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use modulo

ans = (36501 - mod(36501,100))/100
This would give you 365

if you want the 1, it is mod(36501,100)

so this would effectively split your second column into 2 different numbers, you can then re name them etc.

hmmm on second thoughts, if all your numbers on your second column are 5 digits, this can be extremely efficient, since mod is computed in matlab by b = a - m.*floor(a./m);

check http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mod.html it should work for vectors (i.e. your second column)

Comment: Well, it looks to me like you are loading in a long number and you want to split it into 4 columns of smaller numbers. This can be done using modulo (just change the 100 to 10000 etc) and renaming each of them. I'm not sure what your input data looks like. The Modulo is the most efficient way of splitting integer data into smaller parts.

Comment: I've implemented the function however the computer is struggling to implement the code.

T=importdata('File1.txt');
A= T(:,[1]);
BA= T(:,[2]);
BB= T(:,[2]);
B = (BA-mod(BA,100))/100;
C = mod(BA,100);
D= T(:,[3]);
Combined = [A,B,C,D];
dlmwrite('1',Combined);

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

What might take time in your case is actually the use of the str2double function. It is known that this built-in function becomes very slow when the data set is large. You might try to get rid of it if possible.